# Play Framework - Proxy request with session authentication

Tags: java, authentication, proxy, playframework-2.0

I have a couchapp that I want to control access to with Play! on a per user basis. My plan is to host the couchapp on port xxxx, which is only accessable internally, and host Play! on port 80.

In Apache I would do it like this,

```
ProxyPass /couchapp http://localhost:xxxx
ProxyPassReverse /couchapp http://localhost:xxxx
```

But there is no authentication with this approach. I see Play! has some proxy features, but I don't see anyway to add user authentication to this, http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/HTTPServer

Any idea how to add user authentication to a Play! proxy? The code would look something like this.

```
// Routes all request to http://localhost:xxxx/ if authenticated
public static Result useProxy() {
    if (!session("authorized").equals("true")) {
        String pingURL = "";
        return redirect(pingURL); // will call pingCallback after login
    }
    return ok(); // take the original request to /couchapp/xxxx.asset and proxy it to http://localhost:xxxx/xxxx.asset
}

public static Result pingCallback() {
    Form<PingResponse> pingResponseForm = Form.form(PingResponse.class);
    PingResponse pingResponse = pingResponseForm.bindFromRequest().get();
    if (!pingResponse.isAuthorized()) {
        return unauthorized();
    } else {
        session("authorized", "true");
    }
    return ok(); // take the original request to /couchapp/xxxx.asset and proxy it to http://localhost:xxxx/xxxx.asset
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used play.libs.WS to make the proxy calls pragmatically. Here's the code. Currently the session is getting lost on every call, but that's a different issue.

-Edit - The session getting lost happens because the fav.ico doesn't have a cookie sent with it and Play relies on cookies for the session. I added a check for that, but it's probably better to filter that out in the routes file.

```
package controllers;

import models.PingResponse;
import play.data.Form;
import play.libs.F;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.libs.WS;

public class Ping extends Controller {
    final static String playProxyURL = "http://localhost:9000/"; // pretend this is our proxy domain(should be on port 80)
    final static String couchAppURL = "http://localhost:80/couchappTest/"; // pretend this is our internal secure site
    final static String pingURL = "http://localhost:80/pingTest/"; // pretend this is ping endpoint

    public static Result init() {
        return Ping.useProxy("");
    }

    public static Result useProxy(String assetPath) {

        // request for favicon.ico doesn't include cookie :(
        if (assetPath.equals("favicon.ico")) {
            return ok();
        }
        if (session("authorized") == null || !session("authorized").equals("true")) {
            System.out.println("not auth");
            return redirect(pingURL);
        } else {
            return async(
                    WS.url(couchAppURL + assetPath).get().map(
                            new F.Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
                                public Result apply(WS.Response response) {
                                    return ok(response.getBody()).as(response.getHeader("Content-type"));
                                }
                            }
                    )
            );
        }
    }

    public static Result pingCallbackGET(String token, String httpRef) {
        if (token == null || token.equals("")) {
            return unauthorized();
        } else {
            System.out.println("auth");
            session("authorized", "true");
            session("token", token);
        }
        return redirect(playProxyURL + httpRef);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding:

```
-Dhttp.proxyUser=username -Dhttp.proxyPassword=password
```

Comment: I updated the question. I want Play! to check the session to see if the user is logged in. Then either direct the user to the couchapp, or ask the user to login.